# What is the nature of this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Consider this improper integral of first kind:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{t\ln t}{{(t^2+1)}^{\alpha}}}\,{dt}, \quad \alpha\in\mathbb R$$

Its required to find the nature of this improper integral.
We know that the problem of this integral is only at $+\infty$ so we must study it in that neighborhood.

Ok so $t^2+1 \equiv t^2$ thus $(f(t)=\frac{t\ln t}{{(t^2+1)}^{\alpha}}) \equiv t^{1-2\alpha}\ln t$ and from here i tried to make the quotient test but didn't have a result, i had the problem even more complicated.(note:when using the quotient test we take the absolute value of $f$ because the functions must be positive)

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: For $a>1$ we have $I=\dfrac{H_{a-2}}{4(1-a)}$

Answer (score 1):

If $a \le 1$, then your estimates give that the integrand is greater than

$$t^{1 - 2\alpha} \ge t^{-1}$$

and the integral is divergent.

If $a > 1$, then estimate the logarithm away with a very small power of $t$ - for example, adjusting the constants carefully yields for *any* $\beta > 0$ the estimate

$$\ln t < C t^{\beta}$$

where $C$ depends on $\beta$. Then

$$t^{1 - 2\alpha} \ln t < C t^{1 - 2\alpha + \beta}$$

Now if $\beta$ is sufficiently small, the overall exponent is less than $-1$, and we have convergence.

Comment: can you tell me please why did you think of taking conditions for $\alpha$ on the number "1" exactly?

Comment: Log terms are frequently negligible, and $t^{-1} $ is the edge case for integrability of power functions.